# Can I use dynamic model on middleware?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 routes that requires a person to be tagged to access the discussions.

1. `http://localhost:8000/api/fieldReports/{fieldReport}/discussions`
2. `http://localhost:8000/api/agendas/{agenda}/discussions`

Currently, I have created this middleware, but instead of pointing right to a specific model, and duplicate it for each model with the exact same functionality, I want it to be more reusable.

`Middleware\ForbidUntaggedUser.php`

```php
class ForbidUntaggedUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $report = $request->report; // <-- I hardcoded the model, I want this to be dynamic

        // The `taggedUsers` remains the same (identical) for each model that has tagging system on it.
        if (!$report || !$report->taggedUsers->contains($user->id)) {
            return response()->json('Your action is unauthorized.', 403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I've tried to use Policy but it doesn't work, so I think I need a middleware for this.

`Policies\FieldReportDiscussionPolicy.php`

```php
class FieldReportDiscussionPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user, FieldReport $fieldReport)
    {
        return $user->can('view any fieldReportDiscussion')
            && $fieldReport->taggedUsers->contains($user->id);
    }

    ... // and so on..
}
```

`Controllers\FieldReportDiscussionController.php`

```php
class FieldReportDiscussionController extends Controller
{
    protected $model;

    /**
     * Create new instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(
            FieldReportDiscussion::class,
            ['fieldReportDiscussion', 'fieldReport'] // This gave me error "Array to string conversion"
        );

        $this->model = new FieldReportDiscussion;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(FieldReport $fieldReport)
    {
        $discussions = $this->model->registries($fieldReport)->paginate(100);
        return response()->json($discussions);
    }
}
```

I need the dependency injection on the controller because the route is nested with each model as the parent, like this one..

`routes\api.php`

```php
Route::apiResource('fieldReports', FieldReportController::class);
Route::apiResource('fieldReports.discussions', FieldReportDiscussionController::class)->except(['update'])->parameter('discussions', 'fieldReportDiscussion');
```

So, what's the solution for this? Can I make it dynamic (the first request object)?

Comment: I did something similar by creating a parent class, and child classes. Then in each child I defined the database model I wanted with a object named $this->databaseTbl inside the construct of the child. Defaulted one in parent if child isnt set. Still required me to create multiple models tho. Im curious as to what you find as a solution.

Comment: Well thanks, I was thinking of about it too for a while, it should work, but someone has already gave us a simple solution for this, for now I'll just stick with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with using middleware, although you'll need some conditional checks, something along the lines like:

```
class ForbidUntaggedUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $instance = null;

        if ($request->report !== null) {
            $instance = $request->report;
        } else if ($request->agenda !== null) {
            $instance = $request->agenda;
        }

        if (!$instance || !$instance->taggedUsers->contains(auth()->id())) {
            return response()->json('Your action is unauthorized.', 403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah man.. how can I not even think this way.. you saved my copy paste instinct from happening! xD

Comment: Hah, we've all been there! Happy to help out.

Comment: Hey mate, i have problem with this piece of code `dd($request->has('report'));` the `has` method are not detecting the requested instance. It works when I do this `$request->report`, is that `has` method mandatory? *i dd-ed it to check if it true or false

Comment: You can probably safely replace it with something like `if ($request->report !== null) { ... }` or similar. Now that I think about it, `has` is for checking user input, report and agenda are model bound route parameters, so it makes sense that `has` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have named correctly your params in your controller i.e. in a resoruce controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Agenda;

class AgendaController extends Controller
{
  public function show(Agenda $agenda)
 {
    ....
 }
}
```

The first parameter of your request will be the named model, so you can get the model with the `getModel()` function, if you are not sure, you can search it with `findModel()` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $model = $this->getModel($request);
        $tryGetModel = $this->findModel($request);
    }
     private function getModel(Request $request) : Model|null
    {
        $modelParameterName = $request->route()->parameterNames()[0];
        return $request->$modelParameterName ?? null;
    }

    private function findModel(Request $request) : Model|null
    {
        foreach($request->route()->parameters() as $param)
        {
            if($param instanceof Model)
                return $param;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```